# Selenium firefox-69 high cpu usage - Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, firefox

I am using selenium **3.14** with ***firefox 69*** in Amazon-linux . I am running my selenium in headless mode in linux machine from my java code.

For 10 firefox windows in parallel , each window will have only one tab my cpu usage is reaching 100%

I am using 4-core-cpu   16-gb-ram ---> [ [Ec2 - m4.xlarge](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) ]

For same 10 instances htmlunitDriver is taking only 5-10% of memory.

I am using driver.quit() inside finally. If I reduce the firefox windows count cpu usage is automatically getting reduced accordingly.

Is it expected ? if not how to check for leaks .

I didnt installed firefox. I downloaded FF-tar and extracted it in some folder and set FF binary in java code.

Comment: How do you exactly _...I reduce the firefox windows..._ What is your exact requirement?

Comment: I. have a configuration to reduce the number of parallel firefox windows. I running UI testcases.Every 5 minutes my system refresh these configurations from my db . If i change the number of parallel threads in db it wil automatically reflect in next 5 minutes

Comment: this is expected if you are running 10 browser instances.  and HtmlUnit does not launch a browser.